How to generate multiple lists/vectors (same length) that are unique or partially unique?
I have created the following function that can generate a list of 0s and 1s (basically a bitstring) using randomization.
import numpy as np

def generate_genome(length: int, max_individuals: int = 0) -> Genome:
    bits = None
    if max_individuals > 0:
        num_individuals = np.random.randint(1, max_individuals + 1)
        print(f'Will have maximum of {num_individuals} individuals')
        print('Controlled randomization')
        bits = np.full(length, 0)
        bits_flipped_ids = np.random.choice(range(0, length), size=num_individuals, replace=False)
        print(f'Following indices will be flipped: {sorted(bits_flipped_ids)}')
        np.put(a=bits, ind=bits_flipped_ids, v=1)
    else:
        print('Standard randomization')
        bits = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=length)

    genome = Genome(bits=bits.tolist())
    print(f'Genome bits: {genome.bits}')
    return genome

It supports two modes:

without max_individuals - creates a bit-list of a specific length
with max_individuals - creates a bit-list of a specific length but also ensures that the number of 1s is not exceeding max_individuals. The placement of the 1s is at random indices (restricted by the allowed length of the list of course)

This is part of a genetic algorithm I am working on. This would produce samples similar to the ones below:

without max_individuals
generate_genome(10, 0)

[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
[1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
[0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1]
[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]


with max_individuals
generate_genome(10, 3)

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] with bits flipped at [9]
[0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0] with bits flipped at [3 5 7]
[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0] with bits flipped at [1 5 7]
[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0] with bits flipped at [1 3]



My problem is that there is the possibility of generating same bit-lists. This possibility increases with the smaller length and max_individuals are. I would like to have control over that to see how it affects my algorithm so I am looking for an efficient way to create a set of unique bit-lists using my function or even better - a set of bit-lists where the number of unique lists can be controlled by a parameter.
I managed to simplify the generate_genome() function based on a suggestion:
def generate_genome(length: int, max_individuals: int = 0):
    # For the given length (number of bits) the maximum (where all are 1s)
    # is (2^length - 1). The numpy.arange() stops at (stop - 1)
    bits_all_possible = np.arange(2**length)
    # Shuffle to introduce randomness
    np.random.shuffle(bits_all_possible)
    
    if max_individuals > 0:
        bits_all_possible = np.array([b for b in bits_all_possible if np.bitwise_count(b) <= max_individuals])
        
    # Pick a random index between 0 and the length of all possible bit-fields
    bits_selected = np.random.randint(0, len(bits_all_possible))
    # Use the index to select the number
    bits_number = bits_all_possible[bits_selected]
    # Convert the number to a bit-field
    bits = [int(b) for b in bin(bits_number)[2:]]

    genome = Genome(bits=bits.tolist())
    print(f'Genome bits: {genome.bits}')
    return genome

However, this is not a feasible solution in my case because we are talking about encoding and not plain old binary numbers. What this means is that I can have e.g. 3121200 of individuals. Respectively all genomes will have a maximum value of pow(N, length-1) = pow(2, 3121200-1) = ??? that cannot be calculated.
Even if it worked, this simplification does not fix the issue with creating a unique list of bit-fields by using generate_genome() remains. The straight-forward (though not sure how efficient) solution would be to create a list and iteratively start calling generate_genome(). Every time a new genome is created, I can check if it is already present in the list. If so, it will be discarded, otherwise - added.
Currently I am testing Python's set datastructure:
if unique_genomes:
    # Using a set allows ignoring newly inserted elements if these are already present
    genomes = set()
    genomes_len_old = 0
    for genome_counter in range(size):
        genome = Genome.generate_genome(genome_length, max_individuals)
        genomes_len_old = len(genomes)
        genomes.add(genome)
        # If the genome is already in the set, the number of elements in the set
        # will not change
        if genomes_len_old == len(genomes):
            # Reduce the counter by 1 and try again
            genome_counter -= 1
            continue
    genomes = list(genomes)

The problem with any solution that revolves around trying to insert a new genome and then again, if it is not unique, until a certain total number of genomes is reached is that it may lead to a timeless struggle to find the next genome that would fit in the already existing gene pool since every time generate_genome() is called, there is an unknown possibility that a genome will be created that already exists, hence worst case I may create an endless loop. In the past I have added a termination criterion, namely how many attempts there should be before breaking. Here, this is not an option.

How large are your actual numbers?

@mkrieger1 Wouldn't this reduce greatly my pool of genomes?

@nocomment Difficult to say. The actual numbers can be hundreds of billions. :D I am working with GIS data, where multiple regions are combined, each being e.g. 1000x1000 pixels (raster data), where every pixel is an individual (the component of the genomes). Since my genomes have constant length equal to the total number of individuals, a genome's size can be described from 0 to X.Y.N where X = width of raster, Y = height of raster and N = number of regions (each supplying a raster). Currently I am working with square rasters, meaning X == Y but that may not be the case.

@mkrieger1 I think that is a good idea. Much faster comparing numbers than comparing whole lists of God knows how many elements each.

@mkrieger1 I have analyzed your suggestion about creating 2^N strings.The problem with that is my other parameter that controls the nature of the bitfield, namely max_individuals.

@mkrieger1 I did use your suggestion for simplifying my generate_genome(), however 1)it does not fix my main issue, namely using the function to generate unique genomes (see UPDATE text) and 2)it is limited to how far we can calculate 2^n. E.g. for 2^3121200 I got an error that it cannot be calculated. :D Please note that we are talking about encoding here. Yes, even for a bit-filed I have a limitation (namely how long a list can be) but that limitation is far less restrictive.

Can you define some sort of "genome seed", a set of up to max_individuals integers, each between 0 and genome_length. These depict a sparse definition of the geneome array. Then put these seeds into a set to prevent duplicates, keep adding to the set until it has the number of genomes you want to generate. Then convert each seed into a bitstring in a later step?

All your numbers can be hundreds of billions? You want hundreds of billions of lists, each with hundreds of billions of zeros and hundreds of billions of ones? And they shall be random and you think there will be duplicate lists?

@nocomment The number of lists is far less, more like 1000 or 100 000. But yes, the size of every list is very large due the total number of individuals. Each individual in my case is actual a pixel in a raster and I have multiple ones. So even with a tiny single raster dataset of 100x100px I have 10000 individuals. Then if I have 1000 rasters, I would have 100x100x1000, that is 10 000 000. That's GIS alright. LOL

@NeilButcher Beside the seed idea (need to explore that) I do use a set (came to my mind when I was rewriting the algorithm based on mkrieger1's suggestion.

Let m be the number of bits, k be the number of bitstrings you want to generate, and r be the maximum number of 1 bits in each bitstring (your max_individuals parameter).
Some cases to consider:

No maximum limit on the number of 1 bits. In this case, the problem boils down to choosing k unique bitstrings of length m. You can do this by sampling k random integers from 0 up to 2^m - 1. Here's the algorithm to do that very efficiently:
import random
import numpy as np

def int2bs(x, m):
    """ Convert an integer to a bitstring of length m """
    # round m up to a multiple of 8
    mbytes = (m + 7) & ~7
    xbytes = x.to_bytes(mbytes >> 3, "big")
    res = np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(xbytes, np.uint8))
    return res[mbytes - m:]

def rand_bitstrings(m, k):
    n = 2 ** m
    if k > n:
        raise ValueError(f"Can't choose more than {n} bitstrings")

    if k >= n // 3 or n <= 32:
        # Selecting a large fraction of the possible bitstrings: faster to shuffle the whole list and take a subset
        all_bs = list(range(n))
        random.shuffle(all_bs)
        res = all_bs[:k]
    else:
        # Rejection sampling with a guaranteed success rate of >= 2/3 per trial
        seen = set()
        res = []
        while len(res) < k:
            bs = random.getrandbits(m)
            while bs in seen:
                bs = random.getrandbits(m)
            seen.add(bs)
            res.append(bs)

    # Convert integers to bitstrings
    return [int2bs(x, m) for x in res]



This is quite fast even for very large values of m; for m = 3121200, k = 3, this takes 19 milliseconds on my machine.

Generating an m-length bitstring with exactly r 1 bits. In this case, we can do the following:
return tuple(random.sample([0, 1], m, counts=[m-r, r]))

Then, we can put the returned tuple in a set to check for duplicates.

Generating a bitstring with at most r 1-bits. I don't know of a good way to do this efficiently for general r and a uniform distribution amongst all bitstrings. However, here's an approach that will efficiently generate random bitstrings of length m with at most r 1-bits, albeit with a bias towards bitstrings with around r/2 1-bits:
return tuple(random.sample([0, 1], m, counts=[m, r]))

As with #2, you can put the returned tuples in a set to check for duplicates.


For #2 and #3, to avoid the possibility of a long rejection sampling delay, you can check if the total number of possible outputs is less than 3*k; if it is, just shuffle all the possibilities and output the first k (as is done in the first answer).
